# InfoPath If Statement

Tags: infopath, form, formula

I need to add an InfoPath formula such as the following:

```
if(Unit = "Percent"){
   Numerator / Denominator *100}

Else{Numerator}
```

I know the formating something like `(TrueResult | ElseResult) [(BoolCondition) + 1]`

Converted: `((Numerator / Denominator * 100) | Numerator ) [(KD-N_Unit = "Percentage") + 1]`

but i get the error below:

> The expression is not a node-set.
>   (-->(../my:Numerator div ../my:Denominator * 100) <--| ../my:Numerator ) [(../my:KD_x002d_N_Unit = "Percentage")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've got the appropriate spaces between terms. So between any `[Field]` or any operator (`+`,`*`,`/`), and I think your parenthesis, too?

Your syntax looks correct to me. If the spaces doesn't fix the issue, try making a new field to do the calculation and call it something like `NumeratorAsPercent` then make your function

```
( NumeratorAsPercent | Numerator ) [(KD-N_Unit = "Percentage") + 1]
```

Comment: Thank you! I attempted to workout the spacing but nothing seemed to work so i ended up the second method you provided and it works! Thank you for the help!